# Bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 4 snippet correction

Tags: javascript, sass, bootstrap-4, frontend

I used this Snippet into my Rails + Sass + Bootstrap App.
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-select-tiled-layout

It did not work at all initially because of incompatibility with bootstrap v. 4 so I was able to refactor a little and get some elements to work.

The only thing no working properly is hiding the checkbox. I had to change from glyficons to fontawesome because bootstrap 4 does not support glyficons any longer. The structure is basically the same so I don't know what am missing here.

HTML

```css
.button-container{margin:20px 0 0 0}
label.btn-default.active{background-color:#007ba7; color:#FFF}
label.btn-default{width:100%; border:1px solid #efefef; margin:5px; box-shadow:5px 8px 8px 0 #ccc;}
label .bizcontent{width:100%;}
.btn-group{width:90%;}
.btn i.fa{
    opacity: 0;
}
.btn.active i.fa {
    opacity: 1;
}

.btn-default {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class='items col-lg-6'>
  <div class='info-block block-info clearfix'>
    <div class='btn-group bizmoduleselect' data-toggle='buttons'>
      <label class='btn btn-default'>
       <div class='bizcontent'>
         <input autocomplete='off' name='var_id[]' type='checkbox' value=''>
         <i class='fa fa-check'></i>
         <h5>Coffee</h5>
        </div>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use "EDIT" monikers in your posts.  That's an old forum habit that is not applicable here.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my checkboxes. I ran into some issues with `data-toggle` and rails form helpers but I was able to work around that as well

Here goes my code in case someone runs into the same issues.

First I would like to say that bootstrap actually provides all the functionality I was looking for. So I did not even need to use the snippet I got from the link I posted.

```css
label.btn-default.active{
  background-color:#007ba7; 
  color:#FFF
  }

label.btn-default{
  width:100%; 
  border:1px solid #efefef; 
  margin:5px; 
  box-shadow:5px 8px 8px 0 #ccc; 
  background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);}

.btn-group{width:90%;}
.btn i.fa{
    opacity: 0;
}

.btn.active i.fa {
    opacity: 1;
}

.btn-default {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ccc;
}

.checkboxless{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
- @questions.each_with_index do |question, i|
  = f.simple_fields_for :my_answers do |b|
    = b.input :question_id, input_html: { value: question.id }, as: :hidden
    .btn-group{"data-toggle" => "buttons"}
      %label.btn.btn-default
        -# %input{name: "my_quiz[my_answers_attributes][#{i}][answer]",  type: "hidden",  value:"0"}
        %input{class: "boolean optional checkboxless", autocomplete: "off", type: "checkbox", value: "1", name: "my_quiz[my_answers_attributes][#{i}][answer]", id: "my_quiz_my_answers_attributes_#{i}_answer"}
        %i.fa.fa-check.pull-left
        %h5
          = question.title
```

So for the issue I was having with rails form helpers and data-togle. I solved by buiding the checkbox fields from plain html and using the index from `each_with_index` as the needed variable.

If you add the hidden field it won't work. I left the hidden field there commented to illustrate I had tried :)